# Solve $x^3p^2 + x^2py + a^3 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $x^3p^2 + x^2py + a^3 = 0$ where $p=dy/dx$

Using quadratic solution we get $p = \frac{-x^2y \pm (x^4y^2-4x^3a^3)^{\frac 12}}{2x^3}$

I am unable to figure out how to proceed further.

Comment: solve this equation for $p$

Comment: quadratic formula for p gives complex equation in x and y which are not separable. Is it possible to reduce given equation to Clairaut's form?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Moo I an still not able to get your point. Can you please provide necessary steps?

Comment: @Moo I get the idea. Can you provide any hint for substitution of x or y. Resulting equations are quite complex and I am unable to find any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66848/discussion-between-abhishek-rana-and-moo).